# Can't change installed version via NVM for user

Tags: node.js, ansible, nvm

I am trying to install Node in eg. version 12.18.2 for user dev.
There is no issue when I'm doing it via command line.

Theoretically, I run the same commands from Ansible on a server and there is still the first version installed. I wonder how to make Ansible change version already installed on a server.

This is how I install nvm:

```
   - name: Install nvm
      ansible.builtin.shell: >
        curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        chdir: "$HOME"
        creates: "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"

    - name: Setup .profile
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: ~/.profile
        line: source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
        create: yes

    - name: Install node
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
          source ~/.profile & nvm install {{ item }}
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        chdir: "$HOME"
        creates: "$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v{{item}}"
      loop:
        - 12.18.2
```

When running this code first time, there is issue with `/bin/bash: nvm: command not found`, when running second time Ansible informs that it's skipping this installation step as it's already installed. I want user dev to use this installed version so I added this task that will use a specific version for a specific user:

```
    - name: Change version
      become_user: dev
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
          source ~/.profile & nvm use {{ item }}
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        chdir: "$HOME"
        creates: "$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v{{item}}"
      loop:
        - 12.18.2
```

The output is the same as it's with install step:

```
ok: [my-server] => (item=12.18.2) => changed=false
  ansible_loop_var: item
  cmd: |-
    source ~/.profile & nvm use 12.18.2
  item: 12.18.2
  rc: 0
  stdout: skipped, since /home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.2 exists
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

When running the same command directly on a a server I get proper output:

```
dev@my-server:$ nvm use 12.18.2
Now using node v12.18.2 (npm v6.14.5)
```

Also the strange this is, when running install nvm step for other version like 12.18.1, I'm getting this:

```
TASK [nodejs : Install node] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /server/nodejs/tasks/main.yml:120
Monday 05 December 2022  09:01:41 +0100 (0:00:00.870)       0:00:09.360 *******
failed: [my-server] (item=12.18.1) => changed=true
  ansible_loop_var: item
  cmd: |-
    source ~/.profile & nvm install 12.18.1
  delta: '0:00:00.452931'
  end: '2022-12-05 09:01:43.287552'
  item: 12.18.1
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 127
  start: '2022-12-05 09:01:42.834621'
  stderr: '/bin/bash: nvm: command not found'
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

But I am sourcing .profile before installation `source ~/.profile & nvm install {{ item }}`

Of course when I use command line on a server there is no issue even without sourcing the .profile:

```
dev@my-server:$ nvm install 12.18.1
Downloading and installing node v12.18.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.1/node-v12.18.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
############################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v12.18.1 (npm v6.14.5)
dev@my-server:$ node --version
v12.18.1
dev@my-server:$ nvm install 12.18.0
Downloading and installing node v12.18.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
############################################################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
```

TLTR

1. When using nvm use  Ansible skip step and inform it's already installed (Yes, it's installed, but I want to use it, not install it using nvm use).
2. When using nvm install  for not installed version Ansible informs that `/bin/bash: nvm: command not found` even when sourcing ~/.profile before installation.

Doing the same via command line works perfectly. Can somebody help me to find what am I doing wrong via Ansible?

---

EDIT: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε for pointing that `creates` in Change version step that should be remove. Now looks like Ansible changed version, but not exactly:

```
TASK [nodejs : Change version] *********************************************************************
changed: [my-server] => (item=12.18.4) => changed=true
  ansible_loop_var: item
  cmd: |-
    source ~/.profile && nvm use 12.18.4
  delta: '0:00:01.658122'
  end: '2022-12-05 09:40:57.817836'
  item: 12.18.4
  rc: 0
  start: '2022-12-05 09:40:56.159714'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: Now using node v12.18.4 (npm v6.14.6)
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [nodejs : WHO] *********************************************************************
changed: [my-server] => changed=true
  cmd: whoami
  delta: '0:00:00.014623'
  end: '2022-12-05 09:46:05.535453'
  rc: 0
  start: '2022-12-05 09:46:05.520830'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: dev
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [nodejs : debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [my-server] =>
  msg: dev

TASK [nodejs : Check version] *********************************************************************
changed: [my-server] => changed=true
  cmd: node --version
  delta: '0:00:00.023858'
  end: '2022-12-05 09:46:06.998710'
  rc: 0
  start: '2022-12-05 09:46:06.974852'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: v12.18.2
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [nodejs : debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [my-server] =>
  msg: v12.18.2
```

The issue is that there is still the old version on a dev user when I'm checking. I'm pretty confused why Ansible thinks that version was changed for user dev and then when Ansible checks version for this user it's still the old one.

Comment: _`creates`: A filename or (since 2.0) glob pattern. If a matching file already exists, this step will not be run._ > You file exists already, although it has not, I suppose in one of your previous tests, installed nvm like you wanted. Using `creates`, this is the purposed behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing this out, it solves one problem at least. :D